# terraform nested loops for storing values

Tags: terraform, nested-loops

I have below two list variables

```
env = ["dev", "qa"]

stage = ["stage1", "stage2", "stage3", "stage4", "stage5"]
```

My requirement is that i want to  store the values, in such a way like "api-dev-stage1" "dev-stage2" etc.

```
display_name        = "api-$var.stage-var.$env"
```

I am not sure how to write nested loops. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need nested loop. [setproduct](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct) is enough:

```
locals {
  display_name_list = [for val in setproduct(var.env, var.stage): "api-${val[0]}-${val[1]}"]                        
}
```